# Entity Framework Design - Multiple "Views" for the data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a design question related to Entity Framework entities.

I have created the following entity:

```
public class SomeEntity {
    // full review details here
}
```

This entity has as an example 30 columns. When I need to create a new entity this works great. I have all of the required fields in order to insert into the database.

I have a few places in my app where I need to display some tabular data with some of the fields from SomeEntity, but I don't need all 30 columns, maybe only 2 or 3 columns.

Do I create an entirely new entity that has only the fields I need (which maps to the same table as SomeEntity, but only retrieves the column I want?)

Or does it make more sense to create a domain class (like PartialEntity) and write a query like this:

```
var partialObjects = from e in db.SomeEntities
                     select new PartialEntity { Column1 = e.Column1, Column2 = e.Column2 };
```

I am not sure what the appropriate way to do this type of thing. Is it a bad idea to have two entities that map to the same table/columns? I would never actually need the ability to create a PartialEntity and save it to the database, because it wouldn't have all of the fields that are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach is not possible. EF doesn't support multiple entities mapped to the same table (except some special cases like TPH inheritance or table splitting).

The second case is common scenario. You will create view model for your UI and either project your entity to view model directly in query (it will pass from DB only columns you project) or you will query whole entity and make conversion to view model in your application code (for example by AutoMapper as @Fernando mentioned).

If you are using EDMX file for mapping (I guess you don't because you mentioned [ef-code-first](/questions/tagged/ef-code-first)) you can use third approach which takes part from both mentioned approaches. That approach defines [QueryView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716798.aspx) - it is EF based view on the mapped entity which behaves as a new read only entity. Generally it is reusable projection stored directly in mapping.

Comment: What about my second approach. Is that valid to just create a POCO and write a query that will return that object by querying my actual entities?

Answer (score 2):

What you proposed as a first solution is the "View model paradigm", where you create a class for the sole purpose of being the model of a view to retrieve data and then map it to the model class. You can use AutoMapper to map the values. Here's an [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/02/01/view-model-pattern-and-automapper-in-asp-net-mvc-applications.aspx) on how to apply this.

Comment: We're currently using AutoMapper for creating View Models. This scenario is slightly different because I don't want the inefficiency of selecting the entire entity. If I retrieved 1000 rows with this query: var data = from a in db.MainEntity select a; and then applied the mapping to my smaller type, I'm pretty sure EF would not make a smarter query. That's why I was asking if I should create a smaller entity or write the query to do the "mapping" myself.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a generic property filter method that takes in an object instance, and you pass in a string array of column names, and this method would return a dynamic object with only the columns you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would add unnecessary complexity to your model to add a second entity based on the same data structure.  I honestly don't see the problem in having a single entity for updating\editing\viewing.  If you insist on separating the access to SomeEntity, you could have a database view: i.e. SomeEntityView, and create a separate entity based on *that*.