# best practice having multiple Dtos for the same entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, viewmodel

I'm developing a .NET Core application using EF Core with a database-first approach. I'm aiming to enhance my approach when handling multiple requests for the same entity.

Currently, I have entities with a substantial number of properties. For each entity, I've set up a mapping profile file to convert it to its corresponding view model, such as Example1ViewModel, which encompasses all the entity properties needed for GetAll or GetById requests.

```
public class Example1
{
  prop1
  prop2
  ....
  propN
}
```

Additionally, there's an EF Configuration file in place.

```
CreateMap<Example1, Example1ViewModel>().ReverseMap();

public class Example1MapConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Example1>
 {
     public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Example1> builder)
     {
         builder.ToTable("Tb_Example", "dbo");

         builder.HasKey(x => x.Example1Id);
         ......
    }
```

Now, as my application involves multiple screens and forms, each utilizing some or all of the entity properties, I'm pondering the best approach. Specifically, when I only need a subset of the entity properties for certain requests, what's the optimal strategy? Should I create a new ViewModel for each case, containing only the required properties? This way, I can avoid unnecessary fields in the response and ensure a more efficient system.

Comment: Short answer: yes (why not?). But the question is largely opinion-based.

Comment: Agree with @GertArnold. A view model is exactly that, a view of the data that relates entirely with what one would expect to retrieve, and nothing more.  This also means that you only request from the database, what is going to be in that view model (which means less load on the database server too).

Comment: Certainly, I appreciate the response. I'm exploring potential drawbacks, if any, to this approach and gathering diverse perspectives. Thank you for your insights!

Comment: @Neil, I was contemplating the same. Perhaps it makes more sense for me to adjust my repositories to select only the columns that are truly necessary, don't you think?

Comment: Also duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7718833 (and more).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Perhaps it makes more sense for me to adjust my repositories to select only the columns that are truly necessary

Be careful with repositories, and be sure they actually add value to your solution and are used for the right reasons, because they can easily cripple what would otherwise be a simple, elegant, and performant solution with EF.

To the original question about whether you should potentially create multiple view models for an entity for different views? Absolutely. This is what they are for, a representation of a model suited to the specific needs of that view. EF works with the `IQueryable` interface through Linq to easily support projecting to whatever, and however many view models you might need. Mapping libraries like Mapperly and Automapper will work with EF's `IQueryable` implementation directly, and they can work through convention or explicit configuration, including things like flattening entity hierarchies. (For instance having an Order.OrderStatus.Id resolving to an OrderViewModel.OrderStatusId property automatically) Convention-based mapping is a trade off to gain convenience, but it can hide problems as code is re-factored because it will not reveal usage of properties etc. using "Find Usages" where more explicit configuration will reveal these.

Using Automapper for example you can define a mapping configuration and use `.ProjectTo<TViewModel>()` with EF's `IQueryable` to build a query directly to return the desired view model:

```
// using convention for mapping....
var config = new MapperConfiguration<Order, OrderSummaryViewModel>();

var orders = await _context.Orders
    .Where(x => x.OrderStatus.Id == OrderStatuses.Pending)
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDateTime)
    .ProjectTo<OrderSummaryViewModel>(config)
    .Skip(pageSize*pageNumber)
    .Take(PageSize)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Views may end up sharing view models provided the use is purely identical otherwise view models that extend other view models for specialized needs. Avoid any kind of conditional logic within, or when consuming a view model.

Where I want to unit test logic using data like this I will use a repository pattern but I recommend avoiding the temptation of using a Generic Repository pattern. The issue with the generic pattern is that it needs to treat all types equally so it can only support the lowest common denominator of capability like "GetAll", "GetById", etc. Feeding it something to use as a `Where` clause, or `OrderBy`, pagination, and projection adds a lot of complexity and/or puts a big straightjacket on what EF could otherwise provide. Instead, I design the repository where the "single responsibility" of the repository is *not* an entity, but rather then controller it serves. Some truly universal entities and logic can be served by a shared repository (I.e. lookups, authentication related checks, etc.) but if I have an OrderController, it has an OrderRepository that serves Orders as well as returning queries for related entities as needed. The repository itself exposes data through the `IQueryable` which gives controllers/services etc. full flexibility with how to consume the data. The repository can enforce low-level filtering rules, authentication & authorization assertions, etc. and the repository serves as a simpler boundary to mock for unit testing. By targeting SRP at the controller rather than the entity I have a repository that only has one reason to change, that is, the controller it serves. If you base SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) on the entity you actually have many reasons to change, each/any of the controllers that share a reference to that repository.

I recommend considering using repositories where you have low-level assertions such as authentication, authorization such as when writing multi-tenant SaaS services, as well as situations where you want to make code more easily test-able. If these are not requirements for a system then it is simpler and easier to just use the `DbContext` and it's `DbSets`. The EF `DbContext` represents a Unit of Work, while the `DbSet` already serves as a generic Repository.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple request should be mapped to a single command in your controllers. Then you can manage a single entry point in your services. Try also to decouple authentication things to avoid coupling in your services or add intermediate app services